# R, passing variables to a system command

Tags: r, shell, variables, cran

Using R, I am looking to create a QR code and embed it into an Excel spreadsheet (hundreds of codes and spreadsheets). The obvious way seems to be to create a QR code using the command line, and use the "system" command in R. Does anyone know how to pass R variables through the "system" command? Google is not too helpful as "system" is a bit generic, ?system does not contain any examples of this.

Note - I am actually using data matrices rather than QR codes, but using the term "data matrix" in an R question will lead to havoc, so let's talk QR codes instead. :-)

```
system("dmtxwrite my_r_variable -o image.png")
```

fails, as do the variants I have tried with "paste". Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 18):

Let's say we have the variable `x` that we want to pass on to `dmtxwrite`, you can pass it on like:

```
x = 10
system(sprintf("dmtxwrite %s -o image.png", x))
```

or alternatively using `paste`:

```
system(paste("dmtxwrite", x, "-o image.png"))
```

but I prefer `sprintf` in this case.

Comment: No joy with that, but: `system(paste("echo", x, "| dmtxwrite -o image.png"))` does the job. Thanks for getting me thinking along the right lines.

Answer (score 1):

Also making use of [`base::system2`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html) may be worth considering as `system2` provides `args` argument that can be used for that purpose. In your example:

```
my_r_variable <- "a"
system2(
    'echo',
    args = c(my_r_variable, '-o image.png')
)
```

would return:

```
 a -o image.png
```

which is equivalent to running `echo` in the terminal. You may also want to redirect output to text files:

```
system2(
    'echo',
    args = c(my_r_variable, '-o image.png'),
    stdout = 'stdout.txt',
    stderr = 'stderr.txt'
)
```