# check if file is available (not in use by another process) with R

Tags: r, file

How can I check if a file is, *not only existing*, but not used by another process at the moment?

The context is that I am writing my output to the same file every time I run my code. The output is created with an external tool via a call to system().

When the file was opened (because I wanted to check its content) and not closed before the system() call, eveything just hangs. I would like to check that the file is available before overwriting it.

I am looking for a R solution, but I am also interested in a console (system() call) solution if it is interfaced with R. My work laptop has windows with cygwin so DOS and UNIX command are ok.

Comment: I think you can use `tryCatch` and write file if error write to otehr file or smthing else( but its work only if file cant be rewrited while used)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lsof` from unix command line to determine which files are open at the moment:

For example:

```
lsof |grep test

Myprocess  1234 user   12u     REG                1,4     100000         1234567 /Users/user/Folder/test.csv
```

Would show you if any file with the word test is being used and by what process.

This page has lots of useful examples of lsof:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/lsof-command-examples/

---

As you've mentioned, system can be used to call console commands such as `lsof` directly from R:

```
system('lsof')
```

You'll want to choose your directory/filename and then apply the appropriate logic as to whether the file is open:

```
try(amiopen <- system('lsof |grep test', intern=T))

if(is.na(amiopen[1])==T){print('Do some stuff with this file')}
```

To use a variable as the filename ([as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651640/r-passing-variables-to-a-system-command)):

```
myfile <- 'somefilename.txt'
try(amiopen <- system(sprintf("lsof |grep %s", myfile), intern=T))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if R can write to the file, so check for `open = "w"`:

```
file.opened <- function(path) {
  suppressWarnings(
    "try-error" %in% class(
      try(file(path, 
               open = "w"), 
          silent = TRUE
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Will return `TRUE` when a user has opened the file and `FALSE` otherwise.